# Is Sietch Tabr the only sietch with a tau orgy?

Tags: dune

In the first Dune book by Frank Herbert, **is Sietch Tabr the only sietch with a Tau orgy?** For the orgy, people have to drink the transformed Water of Life and only a Reverend Mother can transform the water.

Are there any indications in the book that each sietch has its own Reverend Mother or that the transformed water is sent to other sietches?

Wouldn't that mean that the other sietches are missing a quite important (and pretty impressive) element of the Fremen culture?

Answer (score 7):

There are several indications in Dune that the spice orgy isn't restricted to a single community.

From the glossary

> **TAU, THE:** *in Fremen terminology, that oneness **of a sietch community**
>   enhanced by spice diet and especially the tau orgy of oneness elicited
>   by drinking the Water of Life.*

and from the novel itself, there are indications that many sietches (possibly all of them) have a wild reverend mother at their heart, **though only Sietch Tabr has one that is party to the secrets of the Bene Gesserit.**

> *And she saw the thread of the past carried by Sayyadina after
>   Sayyadina—first by word of mouth, hidden in the sand chanteys, then
>   **refined through their own Reverend Mothers with the discovery of the
>   poison drug on Rossak … and now developed to subtle strength on
>   Arrakis in the discovery of the Water of Life.***

Comment: That's right, there is no indication of that. All the Sietches had their own spice orgys